# running shell command in python

Tags: raspbian, python

When I run a terminal command in python, it throws an error. Below is the code I run from a .py-file in terminal:

```
import time
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
while True:
   if(GPIO.input(12) == 0):
      os.system ('omxplayer /home/pi/Downloads/bell.mp3')
      print("DOOR BELL RINGING")
      os.system ("cd /home/pi/picam")
      os.system ("./picam --alsadev hw:1,0 -w 640 -h 360 -v 800000 -f 24 --tcpout $")
      time.sleep(1)
```

This code is for video streaming, but it doesn't work. The error message is:

```
sh: 1: ./picam: not found
```

Comment: I have had trouble with calling bash-files (like your picam) as well. Usually it helps to insert "bash" in front of the command.. Would you mind posting your picam-file?

Comment: `./picam: not found` means it isn't in the directory or it is but doesn't have execute permissions.

Comment: Is picam in the directory where you are running the command from? You can verify this by doing ls -la from the command line and looking for the file in the output. Please edit your question and include the output of ls -la. is picam the entire file name or is it picam.sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the two separate calls of `os.system` are exactly that - completely separate from each other. Whatever happens in the first call is lost and forgotten in the second (*like tears in rain*).

```
os.system ("cd /home/pi/picam")
os.system ("./picam --alsadev ...")
```

Changing to `/home/pi/picam` is of no relevance to the next call which leads to the expected result - the error that is thrown - not found. Simplest solution here: use the full path `/home/pi/picam/picam --alsadev ...` instead of `./picam --alsadev ...`.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system it is recommended to use `subprocess` over `os.system`:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.

Comment: In other words, when you run the script it should do the cd itself.